# Is there a Rails FormHelper email method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In a Rails application, I came across something like this (in a haml file):

```
= form_for(resource, url:<url>, ...) do |f|
  = f.email :email, required: true, id: 'registration_email" ...
```

Looking at the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-email_field), I can find an `email_field` method, but not an `email` method. I have dug into the source as well, but so far no dice. I appreciate any insight!

Comment: `f.email :email` is not valid syntax in vanilla Rails. It is possible however that it is defined as a shortcut in a forms gem used in the project.

Comment: Yes, the project is using a custom builder, which has a custom `email` method.

Comment: Okay, that's what you were asking, right? Or did I misunderstand the question? :)

Comment: Yes, that answers the question. The email method being called here, it turns out, is in a custom builder.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the `email` method I was referring to was in a custom builder that was being passed into the `form_for` method.

Answer (score 1):

We use email_field with and without a form builder and specify your resource inside it, like in example posted in docs

```
email_field("user", "email")
# => <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="email" />
```

or

```
= form_for(resource, url:<url>, ...) do |f|
  = f.email_field :email, required: true, id: 'registration_email" ...
```

Which will generate

```
<input id="resource_email" name="resource[email]" type="email" />
```

*I don't think there's a **.email helper in general because i just tested and it gave me syntax error**. Needs to check but **it could be that the gem you are using may have defined it for you** otherwise i don't think it'll work*

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am wondering though, where is the FormHelper method `email` defined?[...time passes and I look at the source...] Wait, I get it now! The methods defined in the source are all `*_field`, but you always just use `f.*` to use them! So somewhere, there must be a `define_method` that appends `_method` to the type passed in (e.g. `email`,`text`, `phone`) to produce the field.

Comment: @MorganLaco Yeah on the basis only i wrote my answer :) but just tested it and it doesn't seems to be working for me. Can you show me where you saw it? Also you might want to unaccept my answer :)

Comment: If you look [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L776) for instance, you can see that there is a `text_field` method in the helper, but to create a text field, you use `f.text`, not `f.text_field`.

Comment: @MorganLaco i know that's why i wrote my answer thinking about that. Can you give me a link where you saw .email helper used?